# Azure DevOps error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild] :: NormalizePath (path)" cannot be evaluated

Tags: azure-devops

In my team we have a project with a very long path. When I try to compile the solution of the project in a
Visual Studio-Build task, we get the error:

> error MSB4184: The expression "[MSBuild] :: NormalizePath (path)"
> cannot be evaluated. The path "path" exceeds the maximum path limit of
> the operating system. The fully qualified file name must be less than
> 260 characters.

We use self-hosted agents. I try to fix this issue with [Enable Long Paths in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) and add a `dword FileSystem LongPathsEnabled` to the agent registry. Unfortunately the issue still occurs, what can I do to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/53#issuecomment-459062618) on github : As of Visual Studio 2019 Preview 2 (which includes MSBuild 16.0.360-preview), MSBuild.exe now (as of [#3507](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/3507)) opts into support for long paths. But this does not mean things work, just because MSBuild works, doesn't mean your build will, because many other tools are involved. `devenv.exe`, the main Visual Studio process, does not yet opt into support. That means only command-line builds will be affected by the MSBuild changes.

So I am afraid that long path is currently not supported in visual studio build task. Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Developer Community forum, there has been a such [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351628/allow-building-running-and-debugging-a-net-applica.html) exist in it. You can comment and vote it there.

In addition, it seems that there is no such annoyance with the [32-bit version](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/53#issuecomment-511969054)(restores and builds without issue).